# FreeBSD: jail can not set security.jail.sysvipc_allowed

Tags: postgresql, freebsd, jail

There is a problem when I init a PostgreSQL database in a FreeBSD jail.

I found an article about the problem. I tried its advice but I didn't have any luck and I don't know why. 
There is the link: [PostgreSQL in jail](http://www.freebsddiary.org/jail-multiple.php) .

I also read the PostgreSQL documentation on [kernel resources](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/kernel-resources.html):

> If running in FreeBSD jails by enabling `sysctl`'s
>   `security.jail.sysvipc_allowed`, postmasters running   in different
>   jails should be run by different operating system users. This improves
>   security because   it prevents non-root users from interfering with
>   shared memory or semaphores in different jails, and   it allows the
>   PostgreSQL IPC cleanup code to function properly. (In FreeBSD 6.0 and
>   later the IPC   cleanup code does not properly detect processes in
>   other jails, preventing the running of postmasters   on the same port
>   in different jails.)

What I've done:

- I edited `/etc/rc.conf` (on the host machine) and added the line `jail_sysvipc_allow="YES"`
- In the jail machine's `/etc/sysctl.conf`, I add line `security.jail.sysvipc_allowed=1`

I restarted the jail machine multiple times. I haven't restarted the host machine and don't want to.

Hope someone can give me a solution or some advice. Thanks so much.

This is the message when I restart the jail:

```
 /etc/rc.d/sysctl: WARNING: unable to set security.jail.sysvipc_allowed=1
```

Or when I run sysctl manually: (on jail)

```
 root@xxxxx:/home/xxxx# sysctl security.jail.sysvipc_allowed=1
 security.jail.sysvipc_allowed: 0
 sysctl: security.jail.sysvipc_allowed: Operation not permitted
```

---

Freebsd version: FreeBSD xxxxxxx 9.1-PRERELEASE FreeBSD 9.1-PRERELEASE

postgreSQL version: postgresql-server-9.1.4

Error Message:

```
 root@xxxxxx:/home/xxx # /usr/local/etc/rc.d/postgresql initdb
 The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "pgsql".
 This user must also own the server process.

 The database cluster will be initialized with locale C.
 The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

 creating directory /usr/local/pgsql/data ... ok
 creating subdirectories ... ok
 selecting default max_connections ... 10
 selecting default shared_buffers ... 400kB
 creating configuration files ... ok
 creating template1 database in /usr/local/pgsql/data/base/1 ... FATAL:  could not create      
 shared memory segment: Function not implemented
 DETAIL:  Failed system call was shmget(key=1, size=2146304, 03600).
 child process exited with exit code 1
 initdb: removing data directory "/usr/local/pgsql/data"
```

---

Update:

in host machine, 
/etc/sysctl.conf:  security.jail.sysvipc_allowed=1
/etc/rc.conf :     jail_sysvipc_allow="YES"

In Jail server, there is no extra jail_sysvipc configuration.

sysctl value in host machine:

```
   root@xxxxx:/home/xxxx# sysctl -a | grep 'sysvipc'
   security.jail.param.allow.sysvipc: 0
   security.jail.sysvipc_allowed: 1
```

I still get the same error message as I got before.

In additional, I am wondering if there is anything with security.jail.param.allow.sysvipc? 
Because, in host machine, I was not allowed to set it. (security.jail.param.allow.sysvipc 0-> 0)

Comment: Which FreeBSD version are you using? Which PostgreSQL version?

Comment: Also, is this causing you a specific problem? Do you just want to improve inter-jail isolation? Are you having issues starting Pg up in a jail? What's the background? Include the commands you run and the errors they produce, just like you have for the attempted solution you've written about. Please update your question.

Comment: Same problem here, with FreeBSD-9.1, compiled two days ago..

Comment: Mau be you hit this bug: http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/query-pr.cgi?pr=bin/173469

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem after my teammate's help.

Because I use /etc/jail.conf, I have to add a line "allow.sysvipc" to enable system share memory.

in host machine,

```
  /etc/sysctl.conf
  security.jail.sysvipc_allowed=1

  /etc/rc.conf 
  jail_sysvipc_allow="YES" (DO NOT have to do this, remove it)
```

Answer (score 18):

Solution found. The following does work for me. On the **host**, do:

```
root@host# jls
   JID  IP Address      Hostname                      Path
     3  -               some.jail                     /usr/jails/somejail
```

Find the correct JID, 3 in my example. Then, on the **host**, issue:

`jail -m jid=3 allow.sysvipc=1`

Comment: This poses a security risk because if another jail also shares memory and is pwned, they can mess with the rest of the jails sharing memory, semaphores, etc. Since FreeBSD 11, you can namespace shared memory, semaphores, etc with `sysvshsem=new`, `sysvshmem=new`. For a more in-depth explanation and commands, see https://blog.tyk.nu/blog/freebsd-jails-and-sysv-ipc/ or https://archive.fo/P10Cr if unavailable.

Comment: I meant `sysvshm=new`, `sysvsem=new`, and `sysvmsg=new` if you need namespaced shared memory, semaphores, and message queues respectively.

Answer (score 6):

There are some new features for jail in special granularity, we need allow change sysvipc_allowed for each jail put this in /etc/rc.conf:

```
jail_example_parameters="allow.sysvipc=1"
```

Answer (score 2):

The sysctl `security.jail.sysvipc_allowed` has to be set on the *host*, not in the jail. But if you set `jail_sysvipc_allow="YES"` in the host's `rc.conf`, that should set it for you, see `/etc/rc.d/jail`.

You should check on the host if the value of `security.jail.sysvipc_allowed` changes to 1 if you start the jail. If not, there is probably something wrong in your rc.conf. Try setting `security.jail.sysvipc_allowed` manually on the *host*.

Answer (score 0):

My system required modding /etc/rc.conf before restarting the jail, otherwise it would set both host and jail to 0. I did *not* need to set security.jail.sysvipc_allowed=1 in /etc/sysctl.conf.

```
/etc/rc.conf:
jail_sysvipc_allow="YES"
```